# error "no hay una restriccion unique que coincida con las columnas dadas de la tabla referenciada <<alumnos>>

Tags: postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buena tarde, tengo un problema cuando ejecuto el script de mi base de datos, me arroja el error " no hay una restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida <>
lo que intento hacer es que la clave primaria Pk_numero_control de la tabla ALUMNOS sea primaria y foranea en la tabla TELEFONOS pero al hacer la referencia con la tabla ALUMNOS me arroja el error mencionado anteriormente. Ya he revisado todo y no encuentro la causa del por qué. espero y me ayuden, de ante mano gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido! El error es bastante claro: Como la clave primaria de la tabla alumnnos está formada por los campos Pk_Numero_control y Pk_Clave_carrera, no puedes hacer una clave ajena en la tabla teléfonos que referencie a un único campo, puesto que pueden existir N filas con el mismo valor para Pk_Numero_control. La única solución con el modelo que muestras es que la tabla teléfonos tenga los dos campos que forma la clave primaria de alumnos y que la clave ajena apuntara a los dos campos.

Answer (score 1):

Si una tabla tiene una clave compuesta (dos columnas en este caso) una referencia a ella por una clave foránea también debe incluir dos columnas.

Por ejemplo, tus tablas podrían ser creadas así:

```
create table control.alumnos (
  fk_numero_contro varchar(50),
  pk_clave_carrera varchar(50),
  -- otras columnas
);


create table control.telefonos (
  fk_numero_contro varchar(50),
  fk_clave_carrera varchar(50),
  -- otras columnas
  constraint foreign key (fk_numero_contro, fk_clave_carrera)
    references control.alumnos (fk_numero_contro, pk_clave_carrera)
);
```